# how to give intimation to a browser , when server connection down?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

In my chat application , I am using **primary** and **secondary** servers.

my application gets loaded and initiated via **primary server protocol** to send and receive messages.

If **primary server protocol** downs , I have to reconnect the chat application to the **Secondary protocol** to continue the chat.

Up to this working fine.

But I have to intimate to the browser that **"Connection Server was changed"** in the JSP page.

How can I do this ?

My **java code** to detect and change of the server is below

```
        if(ApplicationInfo.flexProtocol.getState() == ChannelState.Closed ){

            System.out.println("Connection protocol closed ...");
            System.out.println("Old Connection  FlexProtocol  state --->"+ApplicationInfo.flexProtocol.getState());
            try {

                ServerConnection con = SingletonPattern.getInstance();
                ApplicationInfo.flexProtocol = con.getSecondaryConnection();
                System.out.println("New Connection  FlexProtocol  state --->"+ApplicationInfo.flexProtocol.getState());
                protocol = ApplicationInfo.flexProtocol;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Hope you people will give a good solution.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Store ApplicationInfo.flexProtocol.getState() in a variable and if its gives closed state show that connection server is getting changed .